# iOS app to lock screen or turn off device after a specific time

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have experience programming in OS X but have never programmed in iOS. I want to create a special iOS apps for my special needs to prevent my kid from spending too much times in my IPhone/IPad. It's a simple app which allows the user to set the time and once the time elapses, the device can be either turned off or its screen will be locked.

May I know whether this is possible and what are the APIs involved? I just need a very brief idea for me to kick start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not possible unless you jailbreak the phone

Comment: You could look at mobile device management, not sure if it has all these features but does enable you to lock down the device. (no jailbreak required).

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is really special.

Unfortunately there is no way to lock your iOS device or automatically shut down it, unless you jailbreak the phone.

Answer (score 0):

I would set the device to Kiosk Mode (Guided Access) or Single App Mode (Using Mobile Device Management). This will prevent your kid from exiting the app.

You could then program your app to stop responding after the elapsed time. It can't shut down the device, but should lock the screen after x minutes of inactivity (configured in the settings).